# .htaccess rewrite conflicting rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having an issue with some htaccess rules which I thought would be simple. I have some nice SEO friendly URL rewriting in place as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|/images|/templates|/views|/ajax|/uploads|/robots\.txt|/sitemap\.xml|/favicon\.ico|/scripts|/cron|/combine.php|/js|/css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?ref=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

This all works well and I want to keep this. I also wish to rewrite some old pages which Google WMT is reporting as 404's to the new equivalent and for that I'd like to use:

```
Redirect 301 /about_us http://example.com/about-us
```

The problem I have is that the URL that the browser is directed to is:

```
http://example.com/about-us?ref=about_us
```

The about_us is the old link and about-us is the correct link. If the htaccess redirected to example.com/about-us then the other SEO friendly rewrite rule will pick it up and show the page but eh extra ?ref= parameter is confusing it. I am guessing the two rules are conflicting to a degree but is there a way to get the two rules to work together e.g. redirect without the extra ?ref= parameter? My knowledge of htaccess is basic to say the least so I am a little stuck on this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check your apache log?

Comment: Maybe try `RewriteRule ^\/about_us http://example.com/about-us [L, R=301, NC]`

Comment: Why is it that you're using `&%{QUERY_STRING}` instead of `[QSA]`?

Comment: @MikeAnthony I'm using that because thats what the example code said :) My htaccess knowledge is limited enough to have to grab samples from all over the place. Whats the fundamental difference between what I have and [QSA]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` are part of mod_alias, while the rewrite rules are part of mod_rewrite. The problem you're running into is when you mix the two, **both** modules affect the same request, thus two things happen when you only want one. In this case, you need to stick with just mod_rewrite and use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about_us /about-us [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|/images|/templates|/views|/ajax|/uploads|/robots\.txt|/sitemap\.xml|/favicon\.ico|/scripts|/cron|/combine.php|/js|/css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?ref=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Note that the rule that redirects comes **before** the rule that routes to index.php.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guessed there was some sort of conflict but didn't know enough to know what.